# Cisco UCS C22 M3 Rack-mount BIOS Recovery

Tags: cisco, bios, cisco-ucs

So my Cisco UCS Server's BIOS is corrupt and needs reflashed.

When it boots it simply gives me the recovery instructions such as put the recovery.cap file in the root directory of a USB drive then restart. I've also tried it with mounting the recovery jumper, still does the same thing.

After a few seconds of waiting like the instructions say, it just says it can't find a valid recovery.cap file.

I've tried every USB port on it and nothing. I know they work because I've used keyboards on them prior to this.

I'm not able to access the CIMC when it's in this state, so from what I can see my only option is the recovery.cap, which so far I haven't had any luck with.

I don't have any KVM access or anything, just the physical server itself connected to a monitor.

Comment: I'm guessing you are following the recovery procedure, but did you make sure the USB flash drive was formatted as FAT16 or FAT32 and not NTFS?

Comment: Yeah, it was formatted correctly. I actually got it to work finally. I've just been rebooting and hoping and it randomly decided to work.

Comment: Sometimes all it takes is for you to get frustrated enough to write up a question here on SF and the server will fall in line.

Comment: Yeah that's how it feels. I've been having trouble with this thing though, it's my first cisco server so I've been a bit lost. Just a bit more complicated than HP.